# React native Really need to make Pedometer& Step Counter etc

Tags: react-native, pedometer

I tryed a lot of packages,github repos, google fit,rn fitness etc. THere's no way to get step counts.Please help me how can I get step counts.Thank you

Comment: Anyone please give me an example of working code

Comment: I am having same issue. if you found solution, then share it

Comment: :/ I can't find any, is that so hard really

Comment: so sad, +1 for question else i am going to ask same.

Comment: It's still active ,I'm still searching

Comment: [this](https://github.com/Rimma-A/react-native-stepcounter-ios-android) check this. but its return step from 1 2 3 4.... and some time like 20 23 29 23, so not much reliable

Comment: Thank you, did it work for both ios and android ? @kamlesh parmar

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this library (you can install npm packages directly from Github too):

https://github.com/francisli/react-native-universal-pedometer